# How to design ImageViews that stretch according to the screen-size

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a requirement where few of my image views form border areas of an application, and the application will be running on many screen sizes.
I'll be creating a uniform image for the smallest size possible, which can be repeated as many times as needed, and still presents the same image.
I want the image view to replicate the image contained whenever it is increased.

Is anything like this possible?

I tried 9-patch images, but I couldn't find nice articles on it which could explain how to create useful images with it which could suit my need.

Comment: Now do you want them to stretch or to repeat?

Comment: I want them repeated whenever they're width fails to match the width of the ImageView. normally ImageView scales the images, but I want it to repeat them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to write a custom view to do this. Overide onDraw method in it to copy your bitmap as many times as needed.

Comment: Hmm.. that's quite a nice option.

Comment: Any other options available? like the ones which are already there for this purpose and I just have to call them. that will save some of my time.

Comment: Although I have a solution to this by having multiple resource depending upon the screen sizes my app will support, yours was a nice idea. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the width and height of the device dynamically and set the imageview width and height in program.